# Pointer isn't usable in calculator

Tags: c, pow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI 3.142

main(){

    float fn, sn, ans;

    printf("Hello, please enter your first number and second number: ");

    scanf("%f %f", &fn, &sn);

    ans = (fn**sn);

    printf("%f", ans);

}
```

The compiler complains that there is a pointer required in the line with `ans = (fn**sn);`.

What is the pointer required? I tried to put "" in the statement but the output is wrong number, not the power of `fn` and `sn`.

Comment: Do you normally ignore what your compiler is telling you? '"error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘float’) ans = (fn**sn);"' Pretty clear where the problem is... Also, nothing in your code requires `windows.h`, it can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in Python, `**` isn't a valid operator in C.  The compiler is treating the first `*` as multiplication but then it thinks that the second `*` is dereferencing a pointer, which `sn` isn't.

If you're trying to perform multiplication, use a single `*`.  If you're trying to perform exponentiation, use `pow` from `math.h`.

For example,

```
ans = pow(fn,sn);
```

Comment: oh, so cannot use python  math operaters in c huh?

Comment: Most of them you can.  The four basic arithmetic operators, `%`, `^`, `&`, and `|` all work in C.  However, C doesn't have built-in exponentiation support.

Answer (score 1):

What *ans* is supposed to be ?

*ans* is of type *float*.

*fn* and *sn* are of type *float* too.

You can not use the operator "*" on *sn*. You only can use it on pointers. But *sn* is not a pointer.